# Xmx and gc log data not matching

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I ran a test program (adds list with string in a infinite loop) using below `jvm` arguments

```
java -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:gc.log Test -Xmx=1k -Xms=1k
```

and got the below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

In the gc log i see the below collection as the last entry

```
11.242: [Full GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 0K->0K(92160K)] [ParOldGen: 274084K->274072K(371712K)] 274084K->274072K(**463872K**), [Metaspace: 2522K->2522K(1056768K)], 3.0296130 secs] [Times: user=3.28 sys=0.00, real=3.02 secs]
```

If min and max is 1k how come the heap memory available is showing as `463872K`?

Plus in the oracle site

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html

I see a note ,

Note:   `-Xmx` does not limit the total amount of memory that the JVM can use.

What does this means?

Comment: Please reformat your post, it's hard to read

Answer (score 2):

You have specified `Xmx` and `Xms` parameters after the name of your class. Thus `java` executable command interprets them as parameters to your class, not as options to configure JVM. The correct way would be:

```
java -Xmx1k -Xms1k -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:gc.log Test
```

Also note, that the correct format is `-Xmx1k`, not `-Xmx=1k`.

But please not, that JVM will not start with such low value of Xms.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the error, i tried with the below jvm input "java -Xms1m -Xmx1m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:gc.log Test"                             and found in the GC logs the below line before getting the outofmemory "0.189: [Full GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 480K->457K(1024K)] [ParOldGen: 253K->238K(512K)] 734K->695K(1536K), [Metaspace: 2522K->2522K(1056768K)], 0.0310443 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]" , if the min and max is 1m i see the younggen+oldgen showing 1m + 512k which is not tallying :-( , including @DROY

Answer (score 0):

@Nikem responded correctly and I would not like to respond to that part of the question. However, I would like to add something to your second question -

> Note:  -Xmx does not limit the total amount of memory that the JVM can use. What does this imply?

-Xmx only limits the memory available for consumption by your application heap.

But JVM will need memory space for PermGen and stack sizes which are not accounted for with the -Xmx parameter.